# How to query picklist item in the WHERE clause

Tags: apex, soql, picklist

I have the following function to get the available roles:

```
public List<String> getConsulteeRoles(){
    List<String> str = new List<String>();
    List<SelectOption>roles = new List<SelectOption>();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Consultee__c.Role__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple){
        roles.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
        str.add(f.getValue());
    }
    return str;
}
```

I will like to query my custom object where the `Role__c` contains any of the returned list in my above function. Is there a a way of doing this? i.e. :

```
[SELECT Id FROM RS_Related_Contact__c WHERE Role__c INCLUDES(: getConsulteeRoles())]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'll have to use [dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) as [bind clauses (:varName) can't be used with INCLUDES](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm) e.g.

```
string soql = 'SELECT Id FROM RS_Related_Contact__c WHERE Role__c INCLUDES ( \''
  + String.join( getConsulteeRoles(), '\',\'' ) 
  + '\' )';

Database.query(soql);
```

That will build up a query like

```
SELECT Id FROM RS_Related_Contact__c WHERE Role__c INCLUDES ('RoleA','RoleB','RoleC')
```